# How to leave comment on software store?

Tags: package-management

Attempting to write a review for an app I tried downloading, but I can't see the option to. Time shifted back after realizing it was a virus.

Found a program on the both native Ubuntu stores that is a major security risk downloading and want to make people aware of that fact. Would be best if I didn't have to download it again to do so. My account is newer.

So I was wondering if there is a time limit given to accounts like mine to not spam reviews of apps in general. However I can leave reviews for some apps I have downloaded so I'm confused. Would report if there was a option, but don't see one either.

The applications in question are:

- [Tor Browser Launcher](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher)
- Tor Browser Launcher Settings

All help is great.

Comment: You should probably clarify exactly which packages you have a problem with. It seems from your other posts that it might not even be snaps. Please help us validate or dismiss your fears..

Comment: The applications you mention are not snap packages at least. Also, can you elaborate on why you think this is malware? The entire source is on Github, and the project seems up to date. You would need to have something to back up your claims.

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple of ways to achieve this, and I wouldn't leave a review. This is the order of preference in which I'd do them:

Send an email to security@ubuntu.com as per their disclosure policy. https://ubuntu.com/security/disclosure-policy

Start a thread on the snapcraft forum at https://forum.snapcraft.io/

Visit the snap store page for the application and click the "Report this app" link, which takes you to a form to fill in.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Emailed them right away. Can't find the program in their listings on the snap site. However followed your advice and made a post here:

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-software-store-potential-virus/33833

Answer (score 1):

You can report a snap on the [snapcraft.io](https://snapcraft.io) site - see picture:

[image]

When you click "Report this app", you can choose "Snap Store terms of service violation". This would include malicious software that somehow manage to get into the Snap Store.